# SpringBoot: ConditionalOnProperty not working in k8s environment

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes

I have a SpringBoot application with a class that has scheduled functions.
I have another class 'ConditionalScheduler', that is supposed to manage the schedulers based on some properties in my application config.

Code snippets:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class ConditionalScheduler {

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(value = "custom-property.custom-sub-property.enabled", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = false)
    public Scheduler scheduler() {
        return new Scheduler();
    }
}
```

```
@Slf4j
public class Scheduler {

    @Scheduled(initialDelay = 0, fixedDelay = 1, timeUnit = TimeUnit.DAYS)
    public void run() {
        .....
    }

}
```

This works well when I run it locally.
But when I deploy it on a k8s cluster it does not create the scheduler bean.
Even when I set the matchIfMissing property to 'true' it does not start anything.
I checked all places for typos and there is nothing.

Does anyone have an idea why this might happen?
I am happy to provide more information if needed.

Thanks in advance
Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please check whether your configuration file is loaded correctly in Kubernetes. I suggest you to write a simple function to retrieve property value from configuration file to see if it works.

Comment: Thank you. This was a huge part of the solution. The problem was that my jar file was not loaded to the same folder as my application.yaml.

Comment: @PD No problem~